# SQL: Left join for employee ID

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am very new to SQL, but after researching this issue I have been unable to find an answer which works for me.

**TL-DR:**
I am trying to bring in the approver name and approval status to a query which shows unposted journals. Since I am already bringing in the 'Created_by' name I need to match to the user id table twice but with a different column.

The GL_JE_BATCHES gives me the workflow and approver_id fields, and essentially I want to add these two columns into my existing report. With the complication of looking up the approver_id against a username table and bringing in the name rather than the id.

Here's my code so far:

```
`select distinct hdr.JE_BATCH_ID,
hdr.JE_HEADER_ID,
usr.description Preparer,
hdr.CREATED_BY, hdr.CREATION_DATE,
gjb.approver_employee_id,

DECODE (gjb.approval_status_code, 
'A', 'Approved',
'I', 'In Process',
'J', 'Rejected',
'R', 'Required',
'V', 'Validation Failed',
'Z', 'N/A') Workflow_Status

from gl.GL_JE_HEADERS hdr, apps.fnd_user usr, GL.GL_Ledgers ldg

left join gl.GL_JE_BATCHES gjb ON hdr.JE_BATCH_ID = gjb.JE_BATCH_ID

where 1=1
 and hdr.created_by = usr.user_id
 and hdr.Ledger_ID = ldg.Ledger_ID
 and hdr.PERIOD_NAME = 'MAY-17'
 --and hdr.JE_BATCH_ID = gjb.JE_BATCH_ID
  and hdr.STATUS = 'U'
```

When running this code i get the following error:

> ORA-00904: "HDR"."JE_BATCH_ID": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 14 Column: 35

Any assistance gratefully received.

Owen

Comment: Please don't mix implicit and explicit join syntax...  You really shouldn't even be using the implicit syntax at all.  This syntax was deprecated [**over 25 years ago**](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)!  As a rule of thumb, you should *never* have a `,` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Siyual You typed where instead of from

Comment: @AaronDietz Aah, so I did.  Mind must already be in weekend mode :/  too late to edit it now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use valid sql syntax, like this:

```
from gl.GL_JE_HEADERS hdr
join apps.fnd_user usr on hdr.created_by = usr.user_id
join GL.GL_Ledgers ldg on hdr.Ledger_ID = ldg.Ledger_ID
left join gl.GL_JE_BATCHES gjb ON hdr.JE_BATCH_ID = gjb.JE_BATCH_ID
where
  hdr.PERIOD_NAME = 'MAY-17'
 --and hdr.JE_BATCH_ID = gjb.JE_BATCH_ID
  and hdr.STATUS = 'U'
```

when you had all inner joins it did not matter you were using old style joins, now that you need a left join you have join the rest of us in the modern world.